# When I import the data from List<> to excel it autometically add the border in a excel file.How to remove that Border from excel file?

Tags: c#, excel, excel-import

I have used the below code. importing the data from List<> to excel  works fine but it add the **Black line border** into a excel file.how can I remove that border from excel file ?

```
if (id != null)
{
          int mid = Convert.ToInt32(clsPasswordHelper.Decryptdata(id));
          var objMySavedMedicinePricesResults = db.MedicineRequestDownload(mid).ToList();  

          GridView gv = new GridView();
          gv.DataSource = objMySavedMedicinePricesResults;
          gv.DataBind();
          Response.ClearContent();
          Response.Buffer = true;
          Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + "_MedicinePrice.xls");
          Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
          Response.Charset = "";
          StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
          HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
          gv.RenderControl(htw);
          Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
          Response.Flush();
          Response.End();
          return Json(new { success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

[image]

Comment: code create the square Black Border around the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you've used generate html output and client open html file as excel.On this way you can't style excel cells and table.
Use [ClosedXML](https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml) library.with this library you can create a valid excel file and you'll able to modify the style of exported excel.

Example code:

```
var workbook = new XLWorkbook();
var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sample Sheet");
worksheet.Cell("A1").Value = "Hello World!";
workbook.SaveAs("HelloWorld.xlsx");
```